Does Firebase Remote Config Can Survive Process Death?
With process death being the ultimate silent killer culprit of an Android app, does Firebase Remote Config survive system-initiated process death or do we still need to handle the recovery using Saved instance state?

It's not clear what your concern is that leads you to ask this question.  What sort of potential problem with FCM are you trying to address?  Why would process death be a problem for FCM? Please edit the question to be clear.

@DougStevenson oh I am not asking about FCM but FRC. We can use values fetch from the remote config and use it on our UI. The problem is does it survive system process death?

But what Doug is asking I believe is what is your concern outside of the process death, what in your app is your concern?

@tyczj whether it is safe to use Firebase Remote Config to UI as a source of content or state. Anyway I already found the answer I am looking for, just need to look for any documentation to support the findings.
